How to properly dockerize Celery with Django?
I am having a little trouble dockerizing Celery alongside my Django project. Recently I had the need to add Celery to my projects, and I have worked with it prior, but not in a Docker environment.
I am looking for a proper way to dockerize my Celery worker that works alongside my configuration.
This is my django dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9.13-slim

CMD ["mkdir", "app/backend/"]

WORKDIR /app/backend/
COPY ./backend/ .

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && \
    chmod +x scripts/entrypoint.sh

CMD ["scripts/entrypoint.sh"]

This is my entrypoint script (all it does is start the gunicorn server):
#!/bin/bash

APP_PORT=${PORT:-8000}

gunicorn project.wsgi:application --reload --bind "0.0.0.0:${APP_PORT}"

This is my docker-compose:
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    container_name: project-backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/backend/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - static:/app/backend/static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - database

  redis:
    container_name: project-redis
    image: redis:alpine

  database:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: project-postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./backend/project/.env
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"

  frontend-nginx:
    container_name: project-frontend-nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/frontend-nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/app/frontend/node_modules
      - static:/app/backend/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
        - backend
        - database

volumes:
  static:
  postgres_data:
  node_modules:

Ignore the other services in the docker-compose, this is all the other stuff needed for my project to work, running nginx, frontend, postgres, redis, etc...
I attempted putting in a basic Celery start command:
celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO in my entrypoint script to try and get it running that way, but quickly realized that, of course, the worker won't start unless everything is migrated, but I also couldn't figure out how to automatically migrate since I cannot get a connection to the database through the entrypoint scripts, and aditionally I heard it is a bad idea to automatically migrate and that it should be done manually after all the containers are up.
Even considering that I got that working, that also wouldn't probably be the ideal solution, since that command should be development only (I think?), and a proper system service should be started for production environments.
I am looking for all the help I can get, thanks!

I just set this up for my own project so I can understand the struggles you're facing as I faced the same struggles. This is how I have it setup:
  celery:
    image: same docker image as your regular application
    command: celery -A your_project worker -l info
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - redis
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=xxx
      - DB_USER=xxx
      - DB_PASSWORD=xxx
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0

By setting the command in the docker compose file you're overwriting the CMD  set in your Dockerfile. Like this you won't have to change your entrypoint.sh

Are you automatically migrating through an entrypoint scripts or Dockerfile? Also, isn't that command not really suitable for production?

Inside my entrypoint I indeed run my migrations automatically like this: python manage.py migrate and then gunicorn my_proj.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3. I'm not aware of the command not being suitable for production. I'm not sure but for me it's running fine but if you've got a resource which show how to do it instead I'd love to see that :)

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process . In the docs it basically says the command is useful for development environments, but should be daemonized for production. Maybe I am misinterpreting it?

The above document says, In production environments, Celery workers are usually managed as daemon processes using tools such as systemd, supervisor, or Docker. This practice ensures that workers run continuously in the background, even after system restarts or failures.
